# Use gnomekeyring module with Python and GTK3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, gtk3, gnome, python-keyring

I am using Linux Mint 17, based on Ubuntu 14.04

I have installed:

- python-gnomekeyring 2.3.2#
- python-gi 3.12
- python-gtk2 2.24

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
import gnomekeyring
```

But I get an error:

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning:
>   g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion 'g_type_from_name (name) == 0'
>   failed   import gobject._gobject

what can I do to fix thix?

edit:
[Get attributes of GnomeKeyring key with Python 2.7 GTK3 on Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229201/get-attributes-of-gnomekeyring-key-with-python-2-7-gtk3-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python-gnomekeyring uses Gtk+2 and cannot be used in the same process as Gtk+3.

You should be able to use GnomeKeyring-1.0 from gi.repository:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GnomeKeyring', '1.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk, GnomeKeyring
```

As oxidworks notes in the comments, current GnomeKeyring has marked all of it's API deprecated: libsecrets "Secret" D-Bus API (which on GNOME is provided by GNOME keyring) should be able to do the same things.

There's a [Python API reference](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Secret-1) but the canonical reference has some [python examples](https://developer.gnome.org/libsecret/0.16/) as well as advice on migrating from gnome-keyring -- but be aware that the latter will mostly talk about the C API.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the help, how is Python GnomeKeyring working? Could not find examples or documentation for Python and triey almost 2 hours changing my code to it. Could only find this: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GnomeKeyring-1.0 And when I look there for my used methode item_get_attributes_sync I see "Deprecated since version ???: Use secret_item_get_attributes() instead.". But there is no secret_item_get_attributes for GnomeKeyring. Then I found Gtk.Secret.Item. Is this replacing the Python GnomeKeyring?

Comment: Ops, didn't notice all the deprecations. It's not part of Gtk but the Secret D-Bus api should indeed be usable for everything the keyring API did (and it is provided but the keyring). I don't have recent experience with it but I'll add a note to the answer.

Comment: Ok, but Secret is not availible on my system.

Comment: So I try now to use it anyway http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229201/get-attributes-of-gnomekeyring-key-with-python-2-7-gtk3-on-ubuntu-12-04